# How can I grab this value from the xml file?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

This is the xml:

```
 <item>
      <title>El Reno Tornado 5.31.13</title>
      <pubDate>Sat, 01 Jun 2013 14:01:12 -0400</pubDate>
      <link>http://url.com</link>
      <dc:creator>plankbone</dc:creator>
      <description>Chase video next to this monster tornado in El Reno Oklahoma. Check out the people driving on the wrong side of the road to escape it's path!</description>
      <guid>id</guid>
      <enclosure type="application/x-shockwave-flash" url="http://www.url.com" />
      <media:content>
        <media:player url="http://www.url.com" />
        <media:credit role="author" scheme="http://www.ur.com">plankbone</media:credit>
        <media:thumbnail url="http://url.com/80281E/u/u/thumbs/2013/Jun/1/5a1ee391e2dd_thumb_2.jpg" width="120" height="90" />
        <media:title>El Reno Tornado 5.31.13</media:title>
        <media:category label="Tags">el reno tornado, tornadoes, twisters, storm chasing,</media:category>
      </media:content>
    </item>
```

Here is my code everything works except grabbing the thumbnail data from the xml file.

```
                XNamespace dcM = "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/";
                var xdoc = XDocument.Load(url);
                var items = xdoc.Descendants("item")
                .Select(item => new
                {
                    Title = item.Element("title").Value,
                    Description = item.Element("description").Value,
                    Link = item.Element("link").Value,
                    PubDate = item.Element("pubDate").Value,
                    MyImage = (string)item.Elements(dcM + "content")
                   .Select(i=> i.Elements(dcM + "thumbnail"))
                   .Select(i => i.Attribute("url").Value)
                   .SingleOrDefault()
                })
                .ToList();
```

For some reasons im not able to get the value from the xml.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Here is a example that works if there wasnt another element(thumbnail) inside a element(content):

Lets say the xml code is:

```
<media:thumbnail url="http://ur.com/bla.jpg" />
```

This would work:

```
MyImage = (string)item.Elements(dcM + "thumbnail")
                   .Select(i => i.Attribute("url").Value)
                   .SingleOrDefault()
```

Comment: so the example xml you gave - everything will work ok ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be

```
 MyImage = item.Element(dcM + "content")
               .Element(dcM + "thumbnail")
               .Attribute("url").Value
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try using this way

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(url);
XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("media:player");     
for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)     
{
    string attrVal = elemList[i].Attributes["url"].Value;
}
```

Comment: The thing is I could get the url if it wasnt another element inside a element if it was thumbnail -> url I could easily get it I have done it before

Comment: so i do not get your problem

Comment: The problem is that right now the its nested. I dont know how to get the url value, check my update